# How to determine if matplotlib text artist overlaps axes boundary?

Tags: matplotlib, cartopy

I have some code that plots text (city labels) at various locations on a cartopy basemap. Sometimes these city labels can overlap the plot boundary as shown in the example. Setting clipping on the text artists works to hide the parts of the text that are outside the axes, but I'd like to hide the artist entirely if it overlaps or is entirely outside of the visible axes. Essentially, I'm searching for a way to check if any part of a text artist falls outside the visible axes, and if it does, hide the artist.

Example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs, cartopy.feature as cfeature

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE)
# A sample text artist that overlaps the map boundary - I would like this to be hidden entirely
txt1 = ax.text(0.95, 0.5, 'a test string', transform=ax.transAxes)
# Text that does not overlap the map boundary should be kept
txt2 = ax.text(0.5, 0.5, 'a second test string', transform=ax.transAxes)
```

Edit: This is the code I'm using to plot city labels based on the answer below. When I print the extent of text to the screen, it's the same for all text artists. "stations" is a list of city info[[city_name, lat, lon], [...], ...]

```
for station in stations:
            text = self.ax.text(station[2], station[1], station[0], fontweight='bold', horizontalalignment='center',
                                verticalalignment='center', clip_on=True, fontsize=12, zorder=10, 
                                bbox = dict(facecolor='none', edgecolor='none'), transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
            text.set_path_effects([path_effects.Stroke(linewidth=2, foreground='white'),
                   path_effects.Normal()])
            # Remove artists that are outside map extent
            text.clipbox = self.ax.bbox
            # Hide artists that overlap map boundary
            box = text.get_bbox_patch()
            coords = self.ax.transData.inverted().transform(box.get_window_extent())
            print(f"Extent of text1 LL, UR: \n{coords}")
            llxb, urxb, llyb, uryb = self.ax.get_extent()
            print(f"Axes extents: \n{llxb}, {llyb}, {urxb}, {uryb}")
            llx, lly, urx, ury = coords[0][0], coords[0][1], coords[1][0], coords[1][1]
            if llx<llxb or lly<llyb or urx>urxb or ury>uryb:
                print('overlapping', text)
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution requires some tricks. The texts will be plotted with invisible `bbox`. The bbox provides coordinates of the corresponding text so that one can determine which text are crossing the plot's boundary.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs, cartopy.feature as cfeature

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE)

# These texts use figure coordinates
# want to hide this text

# Add invisible text's `bbox` to facilitate our manipulation
txt1 = ax.text(0.95, 0.5, 'a test string', transform=ax.transAxes, \
               bbox = dict(facecolor='none', edgecolor='none'))

# Text that does not overlap the map boundary should be kept
txt2 = ax.text(0.5, 0.5, 'a second test string', transform=ax.transAxes, \
               bbox = dict(facecolor='none', edgecolor='none'))

# Handling txt objects
box1 = txt1.get_bbox_patch()
box2 = txt2.get_bbox_patch()

fig.canvas.draw()  #generate plot to get correct coords

coord1s = ax.transData.inverted().transform(box1.get_window_extent())
print(f"Extent of text1 LL, UR: \n{coord1s}")
coord2s = ax.transData.inverted().transform(box2.get_window_extent())
print(f"Extent of text2 LL, UR: \n{coord2s}")

# Get the plot's boundaries
llxb, urxb, llyb, uryb = ax.get_extent()
print(f"Axes extents: \n{llxb}, {llyb}, {urxb}, {uryb}")

# Texts' coordinates
llx1, lly1, urx1, ury1 = coord1s[0][0], coord1s[0][1], coord1s[1][0], coord1s[1][1]
llx2, lly2, urx2, ury2 = coord2s[0][0], coord2s[0][1], coord2s[1][0], coord2s[1][1]

# Check whether the texts cross the extents?
if llx1<llxb or lly1<llyb or urx1>urxb or ury1>uryb:
    print("txt1 is OUTSIDE")

if llx2<llxb or lly2<llyb or urx2>urxb or ury2>uryb:
    print("txt2 is OUTSIDE")
```

Output

```
Extent of text1 LL, UR: 
[[157.69892473  -6.4516129 ]
 [231.22043011  12.90322581]]
Extent of text2 LL, UR: 
[[ -4.30107527  -6.4516129 ]
 [110.88709677  12.90322581]]
Axes extents: 
-180.0, -90.0, 180.0, 90.0
txt1 is OUTSIDE
```

Comment: This looks like it would work, but it's not working for me. I've got this inside of a for loop that loops through lists of city info (city name, lat, lon) and plots the text on the map. When I print the extents of the text bboxes, they're all the same.

Comment: I edited my post to show what I tried here

Comment: @KarlSchneider  If you change/add anything in your code, it requires a new question/discussion as my answer can't cope with them. Please post it as a new question. Let this question stay as it was.